# PHPUnit, Netbeans and Symfony2 and wrong tests location

Tags: symfony, netbeans, phpunit

I try to understand PHPUnit tests in Netbeans. I set correct `phpunit.bat` path and the `phpunit-skelgen.bat` file as well.
When I try to create test for some file, using the netbeans option such us "create test file" I get correct directory structure, but the files are placed incorrectly.

Next, following the tutorials from web I set the test folder (to `jobeet/tests`), the phpunit bootstrap to `jobeet\app\bootstrap.php.cache` and the xml configuration file to `jobeet\app\phpunit.xml.dist`

Please see the screenshots below
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Tests are in the test namespace of a bundle

Comment: @WouterJ I have `namespace Ibw\JobeetBundle\Controller;` so it's not right?

Comment: The tests are in `Ib\JobeetBundle\Tests\Controller\DefaultControllerTest.php`

Comment: @WouterJ   
No, I don't have files under that location. Netbeans needs one directory for test from a whole project, so I specified the src/tests as my test directory